# My Navigation Bar folds over itself when the window is resized

Tags: html, css

I have two issues to handle:

1. When I resize the window to a smaller size, the navigation bar seems to fold over onto itself. I need for it to be independent of window size. I will provide both HTML and CSS sheets below.
2. Also, I am using Divs to place content, which in this case are photos... How can I make it so that the div expands with the size of the content?

I guess both questions relate to the same issue; sizing of elements.

```css
* {
  border:0px;
  margin:0px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}


    }
    #wrapper {
      width:auto;
      height: 100%;
      margin:0 auto;
      border:1px solid #ccc;
    }
        #header {
          height:15%;
          border: 1px solid #eee;
          background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

        }

        h1 {
          font-size: 60px;
          position:relative;
          left:50px;
        }


        h6 {
          font-size: 15px;
          position:relative;
          left:60px;
          padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #nav {
          height:50px;
          width:100%;
          background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          font-size: 20px;
        }


        ul {
          width:100%;
          padding:10px;
          border: 2px solid #eee;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        li {
          display: inline;
          padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
          border:2px solid #eee;

        }

        a{
          color:black;
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        #content {
          width:100%;
        }
          #main_content{
            width:85%;
            float:left;
            height: 100%;
            border:1px solid #eee;
          }
            #container_one{
              position:relative;
              left:20px;
              top:20px;
            }

            #container_two{
              position:relative;
              left:600px;
              top:-337px;
            }

          #sidebar_one{
            width:5%;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            min-height: 40%;
            float:right;
          }
        #footer {
          height:10%;
          width:100%
          background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          border:1px solid #eee;
          font-size: 10px;
          clear: both;
        }
      .clear {
        clear:both;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <!--DOCKMANN CORP. 10/6/16-->
              <title>DOCKMANN</title>



  </head>
      <body>
          <div id="wrapper">
              <div id="header">

              </div>
                  <a href="http://dockmann.com"><H1>DOCKMANN</H1></a>
                  <h6>Find your balance</h6>
              </div>        <!--END OF HEADER-->

              <div id="nav">
                <ul>

                  <li>
                    <a href="http://dockmann.com">HOME</a>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a href="photo.html">PHOTO</a>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a href="film.html">FILM</a>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a href="social.html">SOCIAL</a>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </div>        <!--END OF NAV-->

              <div id="content">
                            <div id="main_content">
                                <h3>Photo content</h3>

                                <div id="container_one">
                                  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BLMwFmwDcpk/?taken-by=dockmann_com"><img src="/dk_images/R1 500-333.jpg"/></a>
                                    <br />
                                    001 Roxanne
                                </div>                  <!--CONTAINER_ONE END-->


                                <div id="container_two">
                                  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BLMwJyvjVWr/?taken-by=dockmann_com"><img src="/dk_images/R2 500-333.jpg"/></a>
                                    <br />
                                    002 Roxanne
                                </div>

                            </div>            <!--END OF MAIN CONTENT-->


                            <div id="sidebar_one">

                            </div>            <!--END OF 1_SIDEBAR-->

                            <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>        <!--END OF CONTENT-->

              <div id="footer">

                DOCKMANN CORP. All Rights Reserved. 2016

              </div>        <!--END OF FOOTER-->


          </div>    <!--END OF WRAPPER-->

      </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're giving your #nav 100%. So it will be dynamic to window width. Put some static value like 980px, 1000px, etc. Or you can put a min-width on it.

For the second problem. Your #main_content needs to be 100% width.

```css
* {
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}


}
#wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#header {
  height: 15%;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 980px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 20px;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
}
#main_content {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
#container_one {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
#container_two {
  position: relative;
  left: 600px;
  top: -337px;
}
#sidebar_one {
  width: 5%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  min-height: 40%;
  float: right;
}
#footer {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100% background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  font-size: 10px;
  clear: both;
}
#main_content {
  width: 100%;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">

  
  <a href="http://dockmann.com"><H1>DOCKMANN</H1></a>
  <h6>Find your balance</h6>
  </div>
<!--END OF HEADER-->

<div id="nav">
  <ul>

    <li>
      <a href="http://dockmann.com">HOME</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="photo.html">PHOTO</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="film.html">FILM</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="social.html">SOCIAL</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<!--END OF NAV-->

<div id="content">
  <div id="main_content">
    <h3>Photo content</h3>

    <div id="container_one">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BLMwFmwDcpk/?taken-by=dockmann_com"><img src="/dk_images/R1 500-333.jpg" /></a>
      <br /> 001 Roxanne
    </div>
    <!--CONTAINER_ONE END-->


    <div id="container_two">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BLMwJyvjVWr/?taken-by=dockmann_com"><img src="/dk_images/R2 500-333.jpg" /></a>
      <br /> 002 Roxanne
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--END OF MAIN CONTENT-->


  <div id="sidebar_one">

  </div>
  <!--END OF 1_SIDEBAR-->

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!--END OF CONTENT-->

<div id="footer">

  DOCKMANN CORP. All Rights Reserved. 2016

</div>
<!--END OF FOOTER-->


</div>
<!--END OF WRAPPER-->
```

Comment: Thank you; this solved it! I'll use that bit of info in the future, and maybe that can solve my other div issue.